# Why doesn't TensorFlow learn from my numpy array but works with other numpy arrays? (Cubic regression)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

This is the code for my data generation:

```
x = []
for i in range(-500, 500):
  x.append(i)

y = []
for i in range(-500, 500):
  y.append(i**3)

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
```

And I can plot it and everything's fine, but when I use this dataset in my model:

```
#Build model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", input_shape = [1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-1),
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=['mean_squared_error']
)

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000)
```

It gives odd values as a result:

```
Epoch 1000/1000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 646000595173376.0000 - mean_squared_error: 646000595173376.0000
```

But if I use a hardcoded dataset:

```
x = np.array([-5,-4.8,-4.6,-4.4,-4.2,-4,-3.8,-3.6,-3.4,-3.2,-3,-2.8,-2.6,-2.4,-2.2,-2,-1.8,-1.6,-1.4,-1.2,-1,-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5],  dtype=float)
y = np.array([-45,-40.57424,-36.44992,-32.61648,-29.06336,-25.78,-22.75584,-19.98032,-17.44288,-15.13296,-13.04,-11.15344,-9.46272,-7.95728,-6.62656,-5.46,-4.44704,-3.57712,-2.83968,-2.22416,-1.72,-1.31664,-1.00352,-0.77008,-0.60576,-0.5,-0.44224,-0.42192,-0.42848,-0.45136,-0.48,-0.50384,-0.51232,-0.49488,-0.44096,-0.34,-0.18144,0.04528,0.350720000000001,0.745439999999999,1.24,1.84496,2.57088,3.42832,4.42784,5.58,6.89536,8.38448,10.05792,11.92624,14],  dtype=float)
```

It gives very good results, getting down to very low loss values.
What is the issue here?

Comment: The first snippet is two calls to `np.arange` with extra steps.

Comment: The two datasets are not the same. The scale is different, so the loss likely will be too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the compile parameters as per dataset type and values range to get the required output.

For this, Please change the 'Adam' optimizer to either 'SGD' or 'RMSprop' which are good optimzers for linear values. Also change the loss function to `MeanSquaredLogarithmicError()` as your data input has outlier values.

Fixed code:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-1),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(),
    metrics=['MeanSquaredLogarithmicError'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
32/32 [==============================] - 5s 6ms/step - loss: 21.2284 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 21.2284
Epoch 2/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 11.6544 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 11.6544
Epoch 3/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 9.2233 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 9.2233
Epoch 4/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 7.8573 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 7.8573
Epoch 5/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 6.9383 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 6.9383
Epoch 6/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 6.2736 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 6.2736
Epoch 7/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 5.7597 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 5.7597
Epoch 8/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 5.3538 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 5.3538
Epoch 9/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 5.0170 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 5.0170
Epoch 10/10
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 4.7353 - mean_squared_logarithmic_error: 4.7353
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f69501378d0>
```